# How can I apply multiple licenses using the gradle-license-plugin

Tags: gradle, licensing

We are using the [Gradle license plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin) to add license headers to our Java files. This works great but only for 1/3 of the files, because we actually have 3 types of license-headers.

Is it possible (HOW) to apply the plugin 3 times with different include/exclude sets and different license-file?

I've tried to define my own task but I'm stuck since Gradle always tells me "UP-TO-DATE" (even with `--rerun-tasks`) when running this task.

```
task licenseMainOpenSource(type: nl.javadude.gradle.plugins.license.License) {
    source = fileTree(dir: "src/main/java").include("**/*.java")
    header = rootProject.file('LICENSE_2')
    setCheck(true)
    setIncludes([
        'com/company/project/*.java'
    ])
}
```

PS: using Gradle 2.8 on Java 8

Comment: Have u tried running `clean licenseMainOpenSource`?